# Running command recursively in linux

Tags: linux, recursion, find

I'm trying to come up with a command that would run `mp3gain FOLDER/SUBFOLDER/*.mp3` in each subfolder, but I'm having trouble understanding why this command doesn't work:

```
find . -type d -exec mp3gain \"{}\"/*.mp3 \;
```

When run, I get error `Can't open "./FOLDER/SUBFOLDER"/*.mp3 for reading` for each folder and subfolder.

If I run command manually with `mp3gain "./FOLDER/SUBFOLDER"/*.mp3` it works. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `mp3gain "./FOLDER/SUBFOLDER"/*.mp3` from your shell, the `*.mp3` is getting expanded by the shell before being passed to `mp3gain`. When `find` runs it, there is no shell involved, and the `*.mp3` is getting passed literally to `mp3gain`. The latter has no idea how to deal with wildcards (because normally it doesn't have to).

Comment: Thank you! Wrapping exec command with `-exec sh -c 'mp3gain "{}"/*.mp3' \;` worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fixed data structure like

```
folder1/subfolder1/
folder1/subfolder2/
folder2/subfolder1/
[...]
```

and using `zsh` or `bash version >=4.0` you could try

```
mp3gain **/*.mp3
```

But to make sure check the output of

```
ls **/*.mp3
```

before you are getting serious with mp3gain.

Comment: The `**` syntax (which I love) is new in `bash` 4 or `zsh`. Some shells don't have it. And `ls **/*.mp3` is then enough (for those shells understanding `**`)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Just tried this to test how the directory is parsed by replacing `mp3gain` with `echo` and it works:

```
find . -type d -exec echo {}\/\*.mp3 \;
```

Try running your version of the command but with `echo` to see the file output for yourself:

```
find . -type d -exec echo \"{}\"/*.mp3 \;
```

Seems the quotes get in the way in your original command.

Answer (score 0):

this works...

```
find /music -name *mp3 -exec mp3gain -r -k {} \;
```